# Javascript is loading rest of the script also

Tags: javascript, redirect

i am using to confirm deletion of a content.
i have used js to confirm user to delete the content.. but if user cancels the confirm dialogue, it should redirect.. but instead the page is loading the whole script and then redirecting!

the script goes here...

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete??"))
alert("deletion successful");
else
history.go(-1);
alert("unwanted alert");
```

this unwanted alert is also displayed when i am clicking on cancel in confirm dialogue box..

Edit.. 
actually the whole code goes like this.. maybe this will give a clear view of what my problem is

```
    <html>
<script>
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete??"))
        history.go(-1);
</script>

<?php
require_once "config.php";

$query= 'DELETE FROM `sess` WHERE `sid` ='.$_GET['bid'];

if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {?>

<script>
    alert("deletion successful");
    window.location.replace("../index.php");
</script>

<?php
} else {?>

<script>
    alert("unable to delete!");
    window.location.replace("../index.php");
</script>

<?php }?>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `page is loading the whole script` ? And the unwanted alert, should it be part of `else` block ?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edit reveals the problem.

Your PHP code runs **on the server** and **before the page is delivered to the browser**. So even though you output JavaScript code asking the user whether they want to confirm, that doesn't do anything until the page is sent to the browser. Your **server-side** code continues to run, executing the SQL statement.

So basically, breaking it into server and client parts, here's how your code runs:

**First**, this server-side code runs:

```
require_once "config.php";

$query= 'DELETE FROM `sess` WHERE `sid` ='.$_GET['bid'];

if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    /*...write some output to the response...*/
} else {
    /*...write some other output to the response...*/
}
```

**Then**, when the response is sent to the client, it looks like this (assuming the query call returned TRUE):

```
<html>
<script>
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete??"))
        history.go(-1);
</script>
<script>
    alert("deletion successful");
    window.location.replace("../index.php");
</script>
</html>
```

At this point, the deletion has **already happened**. The browser receives this response and shows the `confirm` and the `alert` and does the update to the location, but again, that has no effect on what happened on the server earlier.

You'll need to have the confirmation happen earlier, on whatever page is *calling* this page, so it happens before the server-side code is run.

---

I recommend stepping back from your current task and working through some good PHP and web tutorials, so you can better understand where and when things happen.

Comment: yes but unwanted prompt, i meant some php code...
but after using return, its not showing confirm dialogue also...

Comment: @piyushkantm: PHP code runs *on the server*, before the page even goes to the browser. Re not showing the `confirm` after adding `return`: All due respect, you must have made a mistake adding it.

Comment: i have added return in the code above and that too within {}. it might be i am committing a stupid mistake but cant find that

Comment: @piyushkantm: Your edit reveals the problem, I've updated the answer to explain.

Comment: @piyushkantm: Sadly, no, I haven't done a lot in PHP but I've been able to get by just with http://php.net, which I don't think is much of a tutorials site...